# Increment in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Hello I have the following code which returns me List of type Listitem. I want to increase the value by one for every ListItem Selected.

```
public static List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem> GetMyCompassTUTListContent(List<int> ContentID, Int32 CountryID)
{
    int Counter = 0;
    List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem> litems = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>();
    using (DbDataContext objContext = new DbDataContext())
    {
        if (CountryID == (int)MyCompassBLL.Constants.Country.Australia)
        {
            litems = objContext.Contents.Where(x => ContentID.Contains(x.ID)).Select(x => new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem { Text = x.Text, y = (y + 1) }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            litems = objContext.ContentCountries.Where(x => ContentID.Contains(x.ContentID) && x.CountryID == CountryID).Select(x => new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem { Text = x.Text, Value = (Counter + 1).ToString() }).ToList();
        }
    }
    return litems;
}
```

Please help me in this. I am not able to that since I am not able to find the way of how to reassign value to variable counter after increment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not incrementing the value of `Counter` anywhere, you're just assigning the value of `1 + Counter` to `Value`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot That is the region where I need help. I am not able to find out how to assign that value to the variable

Comment: See @Servy's answer - you'll need to take the action of incrementing your counter outside of your database access. His suggestion of using the `Select` over load that includes the current index is more idiomatic LINQ than using the increment operator as suggested in the other answers, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an overload of `Select` that also provides the index of the current item.  You can use that.  However, most DB query providers don't support it, so you'll need to do your DB query, then ensure that the `Enumerable` overload of `Select` is called to add the index:

```
public static List<ListItem> GetMyCompassTUTListContent(
    List<int> ContentID, Int32 CountryID)
{
    //Note this is IEnumerable, not IQueryable, this is important.
    IEnumerable<string> query;
    using (DbDataContext objContext = new DbDataContext())
    {

        if (CountryID == (int)MyCompassBLL.Constants.Country.Australia)
        {
            query = objContext.Contents.Where(x => ContentID.Contains(x.ID))
                .Select(x => x.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            query = objContext.ContentCountries
                .Where(x => ContentID.Contains(x.ContentID)
                    && x.CountryID == CountryID)
                .Select(x => x.Text);
        }
        return query.Select((text, index) => new ListItem
        {
            Text = text,
            Value = (index + 1).ToString(),
        })
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `++Counter` instead of `( Counter + 1)`

[UPDATE]

try to increment your Counter before put it into the Select():

```
else
    { 
        Counter++;
        litems = objContext.ContentCountries.Where(x => ContentID.Contains(x.ContentID) && x.CountryID == CountryID).Select(x => new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem { Text = x.Text, Value = Counter.ToString() }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: The query provider won't be able to translate this into SQL.